# PrimeFaces pagination not working and throwing exception

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Iam using primefaces 5.0.i used data table in primefaces and displayed data from datatabase.Pagination tab displays in vertical wise doesn't display in proper manner. when i used pagination in datatable iam getting following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.invoice.customerlisting.getcustomerlist(customerlisting.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:157)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:176)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:361)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 56 more
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.invoice.customerlisting.getcustomerlist(customerlisting.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.isRowAvailable(UIData.java:343)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:422)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:401)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:683)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:234)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:196)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:361)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 59 more
```

Here is my jsf page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      > 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{customerlisting.getcustomerlist()}" var="cml" style="width:25px;height:30px;" rows="3"  paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true">
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
Customer Id
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{cml.customerid}"></h:outputText>

</p:column>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Customer Name</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{cml.customername}"></h:outputText>

</p:column>
<p:column><p:commandButton value="Edit"/></p:column>
<p:column><p:commandButton value="Delete"/></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is my bean class

```
package com.invoice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


public class customerlisting {


    public List<customer> getcustomerlist()
    {
        List<customer> cs=new ArrayList<customer>();
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","invoice","google");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select customerid,customername from customer order by customerid asc");

            while(rs.next())
            {
                customer cm=new customer();
            cm.setCustomerid(rs.getInt(1));
            cm.setCustomername(rs.getString(2));
            cs.add(cm);


            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return cs;

    }


}
```

My customer class is

```
package com.invoice;

public class customer {
    int customerid;
    String customername;

    public String getCustomername() {
        return customername;
    }
    public void setCustomername(String customername) {
        this.customername = customername;
    }
    public int getCustomerid() {
        return customerid;
    }
    public void setCustomerid(int customerid) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
    }


}
```

I'm totally stuck with this pagination in primefaces please could some one help me with good solution

Comment: Where is your annotation for managedbean?? @ManagedBean or even CDI @Named?

Comment: i use facesconfig.xml.i dont use annotations here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a Problem with polluting your server and the database with db-connections. This leads to your error, the DB does not allow any further connections.

To avoid this you must close the connections and free the resources on your server, as well on the DB-server.

I will post a snippet with correct resource-handling. Doing this, I will also use correct Java Code Conventions, especially: Classnames should start with a uppercase letter.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
List<Customer> cs = new ArrayList<Customer>();
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "invoice", "google");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select customerid,customername from customer order by customerid asc");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Customer cm = new Customer();
        cm.setCustomerid(rs.getInt(1));
        cm.setCustomername(rs.getString(2));
        cs.add(cm);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Error connecting to DB: " + e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    try {
        // close resources
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {// ignore
    } finally {
        // setting everything to null (allows Objects to be GC'd)
        rs = null;
        stmt = null;
        con = null;
    }
}
return cs;
```

Bare in mind: gathering a connection to DB is expensive. Consider using ConnectionPooling (like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)). ConnectionPooling will open a set of connections to the db for you and reuse them.

Comment: ok but there is a problem with paginator tab displays in vertical position

Comment: In case you got a problem according to layout / primefaces functionality: Ask another question. The stacktrace you showed has nothing to do with the presentation. It only shows your obvious problem with too many db-connections. This problem should be gone if you follow my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
 at com.invoice.customerlisting.getcustomerlist(customerlisting.java:22)
```

That is this line:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","invoice","google");
```

You have a problem here on connection and not in primefaces. Isn't trying to open many connections? Try to open the connection just one time in some other method, and on getcustomerlist just create the statement.

```
public class customerlisting {

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","invoice","google");

public List<customer> getcustomerlist()
    {
        List<customer> cs=new ArrayList<customer>();
        try
        {
           Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Comment: it might be an error but without paginator attribute its working fine.when i add paginator attribute and turn pages there i have a problem

Comment: Ok as u say there is an error in that line 22 i checked and debuged with separate program i get perfect without any problem.you say line 22 is problem tell what to change there???